# Getting the relative uri from the absolute uri

Tags: .net

I have a System.Uri, e.g.,

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/foo/bar");
```

How do I get only the relative Uri out of it:

```
/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What you are looking for is either [Uri.AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx) or [Uri.PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx).  PathAndQuery will include the querystring (which you don't have in your question), while AbsolutePath will give you just the path.

```
Console.WriteLine(uri.PathAndQuery);
// or 
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsolutePath);
```

...outputs the following results for both...

> /foo/bar

Comment: `PathAndQuery` without Fragment, such as "http://example.com/q?x=y#123" will give you only `/q?x=y`.

Answer (score 1):

Going the other way round, that is getting the absolute URI from the relative path:-

**1.Get the directory needed.** 
To go one step down just keep adding a \ to directory e.g. for 
**@"c:\someDirectory\something\something\foo\bar"**

if Directory.GetCurrentDirectory gives **@"c:\someDirectory"** then do:-

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + 
          @"\something\something\" + relative_path);
```

**or**

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + 
          "\\something\\something\\" + relative_path);
```

Without the @ symbol you will have to escape the \ character with another \ character so it reads as a string.

To go one step up instead, then get the current directory and use the 
Directory.GetParent method to get DirectoryInfo and keep using the 
parent property to keep going one step up e.g. for 
**someDirectory\foo\bar**

if Directory.GetCurrentDirectory gives 
     **@"c:\someDirectory\somthing\something"** then do:-

```
 DirectoryInfo directory = 
     Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent;
```

The GetParent takes you a step up and returns a DirectoryInfo object 
now you can keep using the Parent property to keep going up as you 
still get a DirectoryInfo everytime. So I moved up the file structure 
twice.

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(directory.FullName + relative_path);
```

directory.FullName is of type string which is the absolute path you 
want, concatenate that to your relative path and generate a new Uri. 
So that's a work around to go backwards.